# removing row from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have made a table with my own model so cells are not editable

```
String[] colNames = {"Barcode","Name","Exp Date"};
    String[][] rowInfo = new String[mainSuper.getProductVector().size()][3];
    Iterator<Product> itr=mainSuper.getProductVector().iterator();
    int i=0;
    Product temp;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        temp= itr.next();
        rowInfo[i][0]=temp.getBarcode();
        rowInfo[i][1]=temp.getName();
        if (temp.getExpDate()==null) {
            rowInfo[i][2]="None";
        }else{
        rowInfo[i][2]=temp.getExpDate().toString();
        }
        i++;
    }
    prodTable=new JTable(rowInfo, colNames){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {                
                return false;               
        }
    };
```

I am trying to make a button that will delete the selected row in the table (only one row can be selected) but I am having trouble making it work. I tried a few solution from the site but none of them worked. thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please provide your code where you tried to remove the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a row from a JTable like this:

```
((DefaultTableModel)yourJTable.getModel()).removeRow(rowindex);
```

Instead of "rowindex" put in your row you want to delete.

Comment: I have tried it but I get this error:   
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
 at GUI.MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:70)

Comment: Yes, and if you catch this error? Does it work?

Comment: I solved it by making an inner class that extends defaultTableModel. I tried it before but it didnt work because I forgot to add aconstructor.

Comment: Ok, then please set the question as answered.